# How to add Google as search engine in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-search

1. I don't have Google listed among available search engines.
2. Search for "Google" in the IE Gallery finds nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this link to change your search provider to Google.

> http://www.google.com/homepage/search

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=464):

1. Find the search box in the upper right-hand side of your browser. Click the down arrow next to the magnifying glass icon.
2. Select **Manage Search Providers**
3. Setting Google as default search provider:

   a) If Google is listed, select it, click **Set as default**, then click **OK**.

   b) If Google is not listed, you can follow these steps:

   1. Click the Find more search providers link.
      Search for 'Google'.
   2. Click the **Install Search Provider** link for the search provider you want to use.
   3. In the confirmation box that appears, select the 'Make this my default search provider' checkbox.
   4. Click **Add**.

Comment: as stated in the original question - Google is not listed in the IE Gallery

Answer (score 1):

You can add Google search provider for IE8 and IE9 using [this page](http://www.iegallery.com/en/addons/detail.aspx?id=813).

Comment: Just click on the "Add to Internet Explorer" button on that page.

Comment: as stated in the original question - Google is not listed in the IE Gallery

Comment: What do you see when you click on the above link?

Comment: Great find! It's weird that they don't include Google in the search results when you follow the link from IE itself

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you have specified a different language than English as preferred language. Microsoft seems to make Google hard to find on purpose by only including it for some languages. Please go to Internet Options and choose English as your preferred language. Then visit the IE Gallery again and search for Google.